# What does .filter do in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to deconstruct an Angular app by my colleague (I'm an Angular noob), and I see the following code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module("myApp")
.filter('someThing', someThing)
...
function someThing() {
console.log();
}
})
```

Question: What exactly does .filter do in this code? In a very simple explanation, please. It doesn't seem to make the function execute.

Comment: [Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#filter

Comment: Thank you both, but the documentation doesn't correspond why the filter in my example was written as .filter('xxx',xxx) while the documentation lists it as $filter().

I'm not sure what the second argument actually does. Does it assign an 'alias' to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters in Angular are used to format data to look nicer for a user. There are a couple of built in filters like `number`and `currency` but you can create your own like in your example.

Filters are applied with the `|`character. If you use `{{ someData | uppercase}}` in your html it will transform someData to uppercase before shown to the user.

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filterhttps://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter